# Translation of "nella" in the sentence "nella fantasia"

Tags: word-meaning, translation

Since I like singing opera, I sing “Nella fantasia” but I always wondered what does *nella* mean in this phrase? I know that *fantasia* means “fantasy”.

Comment: Is “Nella fantasia” an aria from some opera? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @DaG: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nella_Fantasia

Comment: @Tia27, why are you so averse to proper quotes and italics?

Comment: @Tia27: If you say so. But please keep in mind that as it is now, your question is less readable: it's more difficult which words you are using and which you are talking about (and “Nella” is also an Italian female name).

Comment: I agree with @DaG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, it means "In": "Nella fantasia" ("In the fantasy") answers (even if figuratively) to the question "Where?"

Answer (score 11):

"Nella" is the contraction of the preposition "in" and the article "la":

> **"in" + "la" = "nella"**.

For other contractions of Italian prepositions with articles, you can see [this](http://www.uvm.edu/~cmazzoni/3grammatica/grammatica/prepositions.html).

Answer (score 3):

Even if what other people have answered is true, the translation is not correct. That depends on the fact that this is a irregular construct. Generally speaking "Nella" means in + la, so it translates to in + the. Nella casa = In the house. In this case, though, it doesn't mean in the fantasy, it means In Fantasy; it can also be translated with In fantasies. The closest translation, though, is probably In Dreams, as Fantasy in English has a stronger "Something I can think of, but won't happen" connotation, in Italian, in this contest, it's closer to "Something dreamy I really wish it would happen, whether it will or not".